# is strtoul not endian safe?

Tags: c++, endianness, string-conversion

So I am doing a conversion from a string to an unsigned long using strtoul on both a little endian and big endian machine. The little endian machine returns the correct value, while the big endian machine does not. Is this function truly not compatible on big endian machines? If so, is there a work around?

Code:

```
printf ("%s\n",cLongs);
theLongs[i] = strtoul(cLongs, NULL, 10);
cout << "returned unsigned long value from string: " << theLongs[i] << endl;
```

Little endian result:

```
1099188638048931
returned unsigned long value from string: 1099188638048931
```

Big endian result:

```
1099188638048931
returned unsigned long value from string: 4294967295
```

P.S. It appears that the same number is always returned for the Big endian example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtoul` returns `ULONG_MAX` on overflow. That's what you are hitting. I'm assuming one is running on 32bit the other on 64bit on top of the Endianess differences. `4294967295 == 0xFFFFFFFF`, which for a 32bit machine would be `ULONG_MAX`.

---

Try whether the following works for you on both systems. I could only test it on a 64bit Little Endian Linux so far. If so, you can use string streams for conversion (which is anyway the C++ style to do things):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string sval("1099188638048931"); // your huge value, exceeding 32bit
  istringstream sst(sval); // assign string to a stream
  unsigned long long myval;
  sst >> myval; // convert stream to unsigned 64bit integer
  cout << myval << endl; // output the converted result
  return 0;
}
```

Note, that `unsigned long long` would have to be `unsigned __int64` with MSVC. Other compilers may have again other names. If you are lucky you'll have [standard types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) on all your platforms and can use `uint64_t` ...

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer after trying a smaller unsigned int. Is there any way around this issue or am I stuck between a rock and a hard place?

Comment: @Jeff: I'm pretty sure there is no solution that works cross-platform, because this would be beyond the C standard. But instead of the C runtime you could use the C++ string stream and the `<<` operator to fetch a bigger integer value. I'm pretty sure that C++ should be prepared for this. I'll see whether I can get you a small example hacked together. Will also give the answer of whether C++ is prepared or not :)

Comment: @Jeff: see if your systems have `strtoull` (`strtouq` on BSD), which uses `unsigned long long` - probably 64-bit on both.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED and @TONY: Thanks for the help, the unsigned long long seems to work, but I'm going to have to see if it will work for my application. I am doing a networks project and these unsigned longs are encrypted parts of messages using blowfish. I am going to see if I can get that Algorithm to work with the unsigned long long. If I used unsigned long on the 64bit end and unsigned long long on the 32bit end, would bit shifting work properly? (minding endian issues of course)

Comment: @Jeff: can you let us know, whether it works for you with the sample code?

Comment: @STATUS: Both strtoull and the string stream seem to work fine to get the string to an unsigned long long, I'm currently working on the issue I described in the above comment.

Comment: @Jeff: as for that question: yes, bit-shifting should work. But blowfish would normally see the data as binary data. So assuming the transferred (string) value originated on a BE machine, the encrypted message in the form of a 64bit integer on an LE machine would not make sense to the algorithm. You might be safer with a simple array of bytes here ... but I don't know all the facts, so just guessing to some extent.